# How to show this?(existence of the element)[Galois theory]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

There are fields $\mathbb{Q}$, $L$ and $M$ $s.t.$ $\mathbb{Q} \subset L \subset M$

Here the $\alpha \in L$ and $[L ; \mathbb{Q}] = 2$

The field $M(= L(\sqrt \alpha) )$ is a finite normal extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Let the Galois group, $G= G(M/\mathbb{Q})$ and it is cyclic group with ordr 4

Show the existence of the $\beta \in L$ $s.t.$ $\Pi_{\sigma \in H } \sigma(\beta)=-1$ 
 for $H = G(L/\mathbb{Q})$

---

Solving the above question, I tried to find the $\beta$ but failed.

Plus I already knew the fact that $G(L/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ by Galois thm

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $G(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, the product becomes $\beta\sigma(\beta)$, where $\sigma$ is the non-identity element of $G(L/\mathbb{Q})$. Does that help?

Comment: In my first trial, I thought like you and did it. But the problem is I couldn't find  the $\beta$ which is  $\beta \bullet \sigma(\beta) = -1 $

Comment: Surely $\sigma(\beta) = \bar \beta$ (Here the $\bar \beta$ is conjugate of the $\beta $) What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $M/L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a tower of quadratic extensions where $M/\Bbb{Q}$ is cyclic of degree $4$, prove that $N_{L/\Bbb{Q}}(\beta)=-1$ for some $\beta$.

That it is a tower of quadratic extensions means $$L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}),\quad M=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d},r), \qquad r=\sqrt{u+v\sqrt{d}}$$ Let $r^*=\sqrt{u-v\sqrt{d}}$, that $M/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois means $r^* \in M$. That it is not biquadratic means $v\ne 0, r\ne r^*$.
Let $\phi(r)=-r,\phi(\sqrt{d})=\sqrt{d}\in Aut(M/L)$. That $M/\Bbb{Q}$ is cyclic means $\phi$ is the only element of order $2$.

The Galois group acts transitively so there is $\sigma\in Aut(M/\Bbb{Q}),\sigma(r)=r^*$. Then $\sigma(u+v\sqrt{d})=\sigma(r^2)=(r^*)^2=u-v\sqrt{d}$. Thus $\sigma(\sqrt{d})=-\sqrt{d}$ and $\sigma^2(\sqrt{d})=\sqrt{d}$ means that $\sigma^2(r)=\pm r$. The sign has to be $-$ since otherwise $\sigma$ would have order $2$.

And hence the Galois group is generated by $\sigma$.

Since $\sigma^2(rr^*)=rr^*$ then $rr^*$ is in the subfield fixed by $\phi=\sigma^2$ which is $L$. $$rr^*=a+b\sqrt{d}$$
$$N_{L/\Bbb{Q}}(\frac{a+b\sqrt{d}}{u+v\sqrt{d}})=\frac{rr^*\sigma(rr^*)}{u^2-v^2d}=\frac{-r^2 (r^*)^2}{r^2 (r^*)^2}=-1$$

Comment: @renus, Well... In my question, there are no condition that the field $M$ is quadratic extension. There are only condition that "$M(= L(\sqrt \alpha) )$" Not $M(= L(\sqrt \alpha), r ))$

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense. My $r^2$ is your $\alpha$. In general $M/\Bbb{Q}$ Galois of degree $4$ implies that $M/L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a tower of degree $2$ extensions, where $L$ is the subfield of $M$ fixed by an automorphism of order $2$.

Comment: If the my "$\alpha$" is your "$r$", then What is "$d$"? I regarded your "$d$" as my "$\alpha$."

Comment: Again $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a degree $2$ extension : any $t\in L,\not \in \Bbb{Q}$ satisfies $t^2 \in \Bbb{Q}+t\Bbb{Q}$ ie. $t^2=c+bt,t = \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4c}}{2}$. This is my $d = b^2+4c$. Why don't you say since the beginning that you don't understand the very first definition of field extensions ?

Comment: I confused concept field extension and didn't know the  quadratic extension. Thank you for helping me to solve that.